# How do I change the camera view?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm very new to Minecraft, and my goddaughter asked for my help. She somehow managed to change the first person camera view to a third person perspective, and wants to change it back. I tried out some combinations without success.

[I asked in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8337551#8337551) and discovered [this amazing site](http://arqade.com). How can I change the camera perspective on the Xbox 360 version of Minecraft?

Comment: Not sure if you are being sarcastic in your last sentence, but you do realize arqade.com is just an alias for gaming.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JamesJiao - He asked in chat because he thought it was a trivial question, and they (jokingly) pointed him to this site

Comment: @Robotnik I guess I missed/didn't get the humour :).

Comment: It was a joke. =P (in my opinion, a funny one ^_^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press down on the left analog stick to change between views.

[image]

More information: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition#Controls